# Standard deviation of a dichotomous variable

Tags: statistics

Suppose, I have a dichotomous variable - gender:

Male coded as 0 
Female coded as 1

Frequency of male - 30 
Frequency of female - 20

The mean of a dichotomous variable is just the proportion which has been coded as 1. So, in this case, I believe it is 30/50.

The confusing part is while solving for standard deviation. How can I do that? Also, is the answer a meaningful one?

Comment: How can you have frequency of male = $30$ and frequency of female = $20$... so that the sum does not equal $100\%$?

Comment: There can be 50 people in the room?

Comment: Mean and std deviation do not make sense for this kind of data.

Comment: @user708015:  No.  $20$ people is not a "frequency."

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of Standard Deviation. The sd will be also a function of the proportion. It may look confusing because it is not a common example but applying the definition ensures that the result is correct.